# find the longest sequence S that is a subsequence of A,B,C string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Give a polynomial time algorithm that takes three strings, A, B and C, as input, and returns the longest sequence S that is a subsequence of A, B, and C.

Comment: before other people solve the problem for you, show some effort on your part, both for your sake and others' - what have you tried? where are you stuck? have you found an exponential time algorithm, maybe?

Comment: @Elmi: Do you understand how the simpler 2-string variation works?

Comment: what's "dynamic programming"?

Comment: @bestsss: It means "Type that exact comment into Google and look at the 1st result that comes up".

Comment: @j_random_hacker I know what it should be, I wonder how it managed to get into the tags (if you dont know how to solve the problem the tag, itself, is a small miracle)

Comment: @bestsss: So you were asking that to Elmi as a test?  I see.  For me that was the major clue that this question was homework.

Comment: it's visible it's a homework from 10(hundred) miles away, yes, it was a question to the OP. I can't even think of a real-world problem stating as: "Give a polynomial time..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `dp[i, j, k] = longest common subsequence of prefixes A[1..i], B[1..j], C[1..k]`

We have:

```
dp[i, j, k] = dp[i - 1, j - 1, k - 1] + 1 if A[i] = B[j] = C[k]
              max(dp[i - 1, j, k], dp[i, j - 1, k], dp[i, j, k - 1]) otherwise
```

Similar to the 2d case, except you have 3 dimensions. Complexity is `O(len A * len B * len C)`.

Comment: this only finds LCS length and not the LCS itself. btw, you forgot `dp[i,j,k] = 0 if i == 0 or j == 0 or k == 0`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - true, but I thought I'd leave a bit for the OP to figure out too :).

Comment: @IVlad can't it be done using 2D dp , first for strings 1 and 2 , then for their LCS and string 3 ? ... by this we will require only O(N^2) time and space.

Comment: @ac_c0der - which LCS will you choose if there is more than one?

Comment: @IVlad i meant 1st find LCS of str1 and str2 . 
 
`let their LCS be X . ` 

then find again LCS of X and str3 , which will give final answer .  


`say LCS ( str1 and str2 and str3 ) \`=\`  a units ,  `

`then  LCS ( str1 and str2 ) \`>=\` a units ,  `

if(LCS ( str1 and str2 ) \`>\` a units)  

  then (LCS( X and str3) ) will be `== ` a units.

Comment: @ac_c0der - the LCS of str1 and str2 is not `X`. It is a set {x1, x2, ... xn}`. Take `abba` and `bab` for example. The LCS can be either of `aa`, `bb`, `ab`, `ba`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in Python for an arbitrary number of sequences. You could use it to test your solution for 2D, 3D cases. It closely follows [Wikipedia's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#LCS_function_defined):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import functools
from itertools import starmap

@memoize
def lcs(*seqs):
    """Find longest common subsequence of `seqs` sequences.
    
    Complexity: O(len(seqs)*min(seqs, key=len)*reduce(mul,map(len,seqs)))    
    """
    if not all(seqs):  return () # at least one sequence is empty
    heads, tails = zip(*[(seq[0], seq[1:]) for seq in seqs])
    if all(heads[0] == h for h in heads): # all seqs start with the same element
        return (heads[0],) + lcs(*tails)
    return max(starmap(lcs, (seqs[:i]+(tails[i],)+seqs[i+1:]
                             for i in xrange(len(seqs)))), key=len)
def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        try: return cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            r = cache[args] = func(*args)
            return r
    return wrapper
```

Note: without memoization it is an exponential algorithm ([wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7Ba%5Bn%5D+%3D%3D+K+a%5Bn-1%5D+%2B+K%2C+a%5B0%5D+%3D+K%7D%2C+a%5Bn%5D%2C+n%5D)):

```
$ RSolve[{a[n] == K a[n-1] + K, a[0] = K}, a[n], n]
a(n) = (K^(n + 1) - 1) K/(K - 1)
```

where `K` == `len(seqs)` and `n` == `max(map(len, seqs))`

#### Examples

```
>>> lcs("agcat", "gac")
('g', 'a')
>>> lcs("banana", "atana")
('a', 'a', 'n', 'a')
>>> lcs("abc", "acb")
('a', 'c')
>>> lcs("XMJYAUZ", "MZJAWXU")
('M', 'J', 'A', 'U')
>>> lcs("XMJYAUZ")
('X', 'M', 'J', 'Y', 'A', 'U', 'Z')
>>> lcs("XMJYAUZ", "MZJAWXU", "AMBCJDEFAGHI")
('M', 'J', 'A')
>>> lcs("XMJYAUZ", "MZJAWXU", "AMBCJDEFAGUHI", "ZYXJAQRU")
('J', 'A', 'U')
>>> lcs() #doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError:
>>> lcs(*"abecd acbed".split())
('a', 'b', 'e', 'd')
>>> lcs("acd", lcs("abecd", "acbed"))
('a', 'd')
>>> lcs(*"abecd acbed acd".split())
('a', 'c', 'd')
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is Google "longest subsequence".

This is the top link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

If you have any particular problem understanding it then please ask here, preferably with a more specific question.

Comment: that won't solve since it involves only 2 strings. "Do you understand how the simpler 2-string variation works?" by j_random_hacker has exactly the meaning

Comment: The algorithm is easily extended for 3 strings. You just make the table 3 dimensional instead of 2. If you understand the two string algorithm then it should make sense.

Comment: >>You just make the table 3 dimensional instead of 2.<< Ehh, you did spoil it x.x

Comment: I haven't spoiled anything. He/she still needs to write and understand the algorithm. What I have said doesn't relieve him/her of doing his/her homework.

Comment: It's a he (visible form the name)

Comment: I honestly don't know, but this site begs to differ: http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=Elmi

Comment: @Peter Alexander: Your answer didn't spoil it, but your comment on how to adapt the solution to the standard LCS problem did.

Comment: I don't think so. He/she still has to work out the reccurrence relation, which essentially requires that you understand the algorithm fully.

Comment: I didn't say there was not work to be done, but you removed the aha moment from the problem which is where people are going to grow. What remains is just mechanical now.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: I didn't mean the 1st name but the family. The poster is from Azerbaijan and bears a slavic name (and possibly a Russian descent); Men slavic names end w/ -ov for men, -ova denotes women. (-ov par means something like 'of')