# Subsequence of strings

Tags: python

I implemented a python function that returns the longest common subsequence of 2 strings. Now, I'd like to implement a function that returns the longest common subsequence of any number of strings.

I found this help for 3 strings:

```
dp[i, j, k] = / 1 + dp[i - 1, j - 1, k - 1] if A[i] = B[j] = C[k]
              \ max(dp[i - 1, j, k], dp[i, j - 1, k], dp[i, j, k - 1]) otherwise
```

But I don't really understand this hint.
So, I'd be thankful if anybody could help me.
Best regards, Mark

Comment: if this is homework, please use the `homework` tag, thanks!

Comment: By "found help" do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705276/find-the-longest-sequence-s-that-is-a-subsequence-of-a-b-c-string?

Comment: @ninjagecko: No, it's just a problem I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The LCS problem is NPComplete for an unbound number of string n.  meaning, there is no known polynomial algorithm capable of solving this. Also meaning that you can drop the DP solution :p

Here's a link to an heuristic method to approximate the LCS of multiple strings.

http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI10/paper/download/1559/2197

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in `O(N log(N))` time (where N is combined length of sequences) by doing something akin to a binary search with a rolling hash.

Note that the length of the longest possible common sequence is the length of the smallest sequence, `smallestLength`. Proceed as follows:

Initialization:

- assume the length of the longest common subsequence (which we call `a`) is `a` = `smallestLength/2`

Algorithm:

- `iteration_number += 1`
- scan through all lists (in parallel if you want!) and perform a [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash); this will generate len(list)-(a-1) hashes for each list
- insert all the hashes into a set data structure (one set per list) to achieve O(1) lookup time
- check to see if any of the hashes collide (take the intersection of all the sets): if there are one or more collisions, manually confirm that there is an `a`-length subsequence common subsequence in those positions, since the hashes might be wrong (though this will never occur in practice if you choose a sufficiently fine hash)
- did you find a shared sequence?

  - if you find such a sequence, repeat the above steps, but increase the assumed length like you would in binary search (add `smallestlength/2**iteration_number`)
  - if you don't find such a sequence, repeat the above steps, but decrease the assumed length like you would in a binary search (subtract `smallestlength/2**iteration_number`)

Comment: Did I... just find an O(numseq*seqlen log(numseq*seqlen)) solution to an algorithm that Wikipedia only has an exponential O(numseq*(seqlen^numseq)) solution to, and claims is NP-hard?...

Comment: Ah no, this is only an algorithm to find the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem ; this is different from the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest-common_subsequence_problem (a subsequence of `abcde` might for example be `b,d,e`, whereas a substring must be continuous, e.g. `bcd`)

Comment: In fact: There's a difference between subsequence and substring. Example for subsequence: "Hello", "Lopez" --> "e, o"
Example for substring: "Hello", "Lopez" --> ""

Answer (score 0):

A solution in python3 would be:

```
#Uses python3
import sys
def calc_cache_pos(strings, indexes):
    factor = 1
    pos = 0
    for s, i in zip(strings, indexes):
        pos += i * factor
        factor *= len(s)
    return pos

def lcs_back(strings, indexes, cache):
    if -1 in indexes:
        return ""
    match = all(strings[0][indexes[0]] == s[i]
                for s, i in zip(strings, indexes))
    if match:
        new_indexes = [i - 1 for i in indexes]
        result = lcs_back(strings, new_indexes, cache) + strings[0][indexes[0]]
    else:
        substrings = [""] * len(strings)
        for n in range(len(strings)):
            if indexes[n] > 0:
                new_indexes = indexes[:]
                new_indexes[n] -= 1
                cache_pos = calc_cache_pos(strings, new_indexes)
                if cache[cache_pos] is None:
                    substrings[n] = lcs_back(strings, new_indexes, cache)
                else:
                    substrings[n] = cache[cache_pos]
        result = max(substrings, key=len)
    cache[calc_cache_pos(strings, indexes)] = result
    return result

def lcs(strings):
        if len(strings) == 0:
        return ""
    elif len(strings) == 1:
        return strings[0]
    else:
        cache_size = 1
        for s in strings:
            cache_size *= len(s)
        cache = [None] * cache_size
        indexes = [len(s) - 1 for s in strings]
        return (lcs_back(strings, indexes, cache))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    an = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    a1 = data[:an]
    data = data[an:]
    bn = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    b1 = data[:bn]
    data = data[bn:]
    cn = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    c1 = data[:cn]
    a = ''
    for i in a1:
        a = a + i
    b = ''
    for i in b1:
        b = b + i
    c = ''
    for i in c1:
        c = c + i
    print(lcs([a, b, c]))
```

This reads the input of 3+ arrays, each char followed by a space. **Before each array enter the size of the array.** An input would be

**INPUT**:

8

a b a c b d a b

6

b d c a b a

6

c b a c a a

**OUTPUT**:

baa

Comment: The input statement is wrong, you might want to change the int in map to str

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def lcs_of_2(a, b):
    """
    get longest common string
    :param a:
    :param b:
    :return:
    """
    match = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b))
    return a[match[0]: match[0] + match[2]]


def lcs_of_list(*args):
    """
    get longest common string of list
    :param args:
    :return:
    """
    if len(args) == 2:
        return lcs_of_2(args[0], args[1])
    first = args[0]
    remains = args[1:]
    return lcs_of_2(first, lcs_of_list(*remains))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 'abcdef'
    b = 'abbbbabcdeffff'
    c = 'bcdefff'
    print(lcs_of_list(a, b, c))
```

result:

```
bcdef
```